# Problem to insert into mysql with ajax and php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, forms

I want to insert in 2 tables of mysql, one table is about information of a product and the other one is for the images of those products.
I have this form

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload-multi-images">
  <div class="form-group">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required autocomplete="off">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label>Price</label>
      <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" required autocomplete="off">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label>Stock</label>
      <input type="text" name="stock" class="form-control" required autocomplete="off">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" id="add-photo-container">
           <div class="add-new-photo first" id="add-photo">
               <span><i class="icon-camera"></i></span>
           </div>
           <input type="file" multiple id="add-new-photo">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="button-container">
      <button type="submit">Subir imágenes</button>
  </div> 
</form>
```

I get the images and the information with this JS

```
   $(document).on("submit", "#upload-multi-images", function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

   $(document).on("submit", "#upload-multi-images", function (e) {
    
    var namePro = document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value;
    var price = document.getElementsByName('price')[0].value;
    var stock = document.getElementsByName('stock')[0].value; 

    formData.append('namePro', namePro);
    formData.append('price', price);
    formData.append('stock', stock);

    e.preventDefault();
    
    //Envio mediante Ajax
    $.ajax({
        url: "upload.php",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function () {
            loading(true, "Adding photo...");
        },
        success: function (res) {
            loading(false);
            if (res.status == "true") {
                createImages(res.all_ids);
                $("#Images form .row > div:not(#add-photo-container)").remove();
                formData = new FormData();
            } else {
                alert(res.error);
            }
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

Then y send the images to this php to send them to mysql

```
$namePRO = $_REQUEST['namePro'];
$price = $_REQUEST['price'];
$stock = $_REQUEST['stock'];

$insertDatos = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO products (name , price, stock) VALUES (:name, :price, :stock)");
$wasUploadedDATA = $insertDatos->execute(array(
    ":name" => $namePRO,
    ":price" => $price,
    ":stock" => $stock,
));

$idPRO = $conexion->lastInsertId();

if (isset($_FILES) && !empty($_FILES)) {
$files = array_filter($_FILES, function($item) {
    return $item["name"][0] != "";
});

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $tmp_name = $file["tmp_name"];
    $name = $file["name"];
    $path = "/images/$name";
    $pathSYS = "/var/www/html/images/$name";
    $insertImages = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO product_files (id_pro, name, web_path, system_path) VALUES (:idPRO, :name, :path, :pathSYS)");
    $wasUploaded = $insertImages->execute(array(
        ":name" => $name,
        ":idPRO" => $idPRO,
        ":path" => $path,
        ":pathSYS" => $pathSYS,
    ));

    if ($wasUploaded) {
        $id = $conexion->lastInsertId();
        $data["all_ids"]["id_$id"]["id"] = $id;
        $data["all_ids"]["id_$id"]["name"] = $name;
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "images/$name");
    }
    else {
        die("There was an error. Please contact with the admin.");
    }
}
```

}

I also have these other JS but I think they are not very important

```
function getRandomString(length) {
var text = "";
var possible = 
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

return text;
  }
   function createPreview(file, id) {
   var imgCodified = URL.createObjectURL(file);
   var img = $('<div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" 
 id="' 
+ id + '"><div class="image-container"> <figure> <img src="' + imgCodified + 
'" alt="Foto del usuario"> <figcaption> <i class="icon-cross"></i> 
</figcaption> </figure> </div></div>');
$(img).insertBefore("#add-photo-container");
}
function createImages(all_ids) {
for (const key in all_ids) {
    var image = all_ids[key];

    var img = $('<div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" 
    data-id="' + image.id + '"><div class="image-container"> <figure> <img 
    src="images/' + image.name + '" alt="Foto del usuario"> <figcaption> <i 
   class="icon-cross"></i> </figcaption> </figure> </div></div>');
    $("#my-images").append(img);
}
```

}

```
function showModal(card) {
$("#" + card).show();
$(".modal").addClass("show");
}

function closeModal() {
$(".modal").removeClass("show");
setTimeout(function () {
$(".modal .modal-card").hide();
}, 300);
}

function loading(status, tag) {
if (status) {
$("#loading .tag").text(tag);
showModal("loading");
}
else {
closeModal();
}
}

function showMessage(message) {
$("#Message .tag").text(message);
showModal("Message");
}
```

Comment: Just try to add the rest of the form elements to your formData object

Comment: I did that, but i couldn't get the information in the php

Comment: Can you please share with us the php code for getting other form elements?

Comment: I tried with $_POST also, but didn't work. I edited the question with the code you are asking

Comment: You php part looks find, how are you adding those elements to your formData object? Can you please share that part with us as well?

Comment: Sure, I added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have all of your code, but I've identified the issue in your code and I'll just add add the fix here for you.

First of all, if you are using jquery, it's better to write your code in a unified format and use jquery everywhere and not switch between jquery and plain JavaScript.
Having that said, instead of using `document.getElementsByName` you can easily add `id` attribute to your html element and access them with `$('#<id>')` way in jquery.

Second, even if you are using javascript to grab your html element data, what you are doing is wrong. `var namePro = document.getElementsByName('name');` will select the whole html `<input>` object and not it's value. So you have to change it to: `document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value`

So you have 2 options:

1- Use what you have already and just change it a bit to:

```
var namePro = document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value;
var price = document.getElementsByName('price')[0].value;
var stock = document.getElementsByName('stock')[0].value;
```

2- Or for switching to jquery, you need to add id to all of these elements in your html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" required autocomplete="off">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Price</label>
    <input type="text" id="price" name="price" class="form-control" required autocomplete="off">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Stock</label>
    <input type="text" id="stock" name="stock" class="form-control" required autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

And then change you JavaScript to:

```
formData.append('name', $('#name').val());
formData.append('price', $('#price').val());
formData.append('stock', $('#stock').val());
```

## Update:

The sample code which works on my machine is like this:

**HTML:**

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload-multi-images">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Price</label>
        <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" required autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Stock</label>
        <input type="text" name="stock" class="form-control" required autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" id="add-photo-container">
            <div class="add-new-photo first" id="add-photo">
                <span><i class="icon-camera"></i></span>
            </div>
            <input type="file" multiple id="add-new-photo">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button-container">
        <button type="submit">Subir imágenes</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JS #1:**

```
var formData = new FormData();
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".modal").on("click", function (e) {
        console.log(e);
        if (($(e.target).hasClass("modal-main") || $(e.target).hasClass("close-modal")) && $("#loading").css("display") == "none") {
            closeModal();
        }
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#add-photo", function(){
        $("#add-new-photo").click();
    });


    $(document).on("change", "#add-new-photo", function () {
        var files = this.files;
        var element;
        var supportedImages = ["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"];
        var InvalidElementFound = false;

        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            element = files[i];

            if (supportedImages.indexOf(element.type) != -1) {
                var id = getRandomString(7);
                createPreview(element, id);
                formData.append(id, element);
            }
            else {
                InvalidElementFound = true;
            }
        }

        if (InvalidElementFound) {
            showMessage("Invalid Elements Found.");
        }
        else {
            showMessage("All the files were uploaded succesfully.");
        }
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#Images .image-container", function(e){
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        var id = $(parent).attr("id");
        formData.delete(id);
        $(parent).remove();
    });

    $(document).on("submit", "#upload-multi-images", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var namePro = document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value;
        var price = document.getElementsByName('price')[0].value;
        var stock = document.getElementsByName('stock')[0].value; 

        formData.append('namePro', namePro);
        formData.append('price', price);
        formData.append('stock', stock);

        //Envio mediante Ajax
        $.ajax({
            url: "upload.php",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            beforeSend: function () {
                loading(true, "Adding photo...");
            },
            success: function (res) {
                console.log('success');
                console.log(res);
                loading(false);
                if (res.status == "true") {
                    createImages(res.all_ids);
                    $("#Images form .row > div:not(#add-photo-container)").remove();
                    formData = new FormData();
                } else {
                    alert(res.error);
                }
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log('error');
                console.log(e.responseText);
            }
        });
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#MyImages .image-container", function (e) {
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        var id = $(parent).attr("data-id");
        var data = {
            id : id
        }

        $.post("delete.php", data, function(res) {
            if (res == "true") {
                showMessage("¡Images successfully removed!");
                $(parent).remove();
            }
            else {
                showMessage("Sorry, there was an error uploading the images.");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**JS #2:**

```
function getRandomString(length) {
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }

    return text;
}

function createPreview(file, id) {
    var imgCodified = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    var img = $('<div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" id="'+ id + '"><div class="image-container"> <figure> <img src="' + imgCodified + '" alt="Foto del usuario"> <figcaption> <i class="icon-cross"></i></figcaption> </figure> </div></div>');
    $(img).insertBefore("#add-photo-container");
}

function createImages(all_ids) {
    for (const key in all_ids) {
        var image = all_ids[key];

        var img = $('<div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" data-id="' + image.id + '"><div class="image-container"> <figure> <img src="images/' + image.name + '" alt="Foto del usuario"> <figcaption> <i class="icon-cross"></i> </figcaption> </figure> </div></div>');
        $("#my-images").append(img);
    }    
}

function showModal(card) {
    $("#" + card).show();
    $(".modal").addClass("show");
}

function closeModal() {
    $(".modal").removeClass("show");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".modal .modal-card").hide();
    }, 300);
}

function loading(status, tag) {
    if (status) {
        $("#loading .tag").text(tag);
        showModal("loading");
    }
    else {
        closeModal();
    }
}

function showMessage(message) {
    $("#Message .tag").text(message);
    showModal("Message");
}
```

**PHP: (upload.php)**

```
$arr_ajax = array();

$arr_ajax['namePro'] = $_REQUEST['namePro'];
$arr_ajax['price'] = $_REQUEST['price'];
$arr_ajax['stock'] = $_REQUEST['stock'];

if (isset($_FILES) && !empty($_FILES)) {
    $files = array_filter($_FILES, function($item) {
        return $item["name"][0] != "";
    });
    
    $iCnt = 0;
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $arr_ajax['Filename'.$iCnt] = $file["name"];
        $iCnt++;
    }
}

echo json_encode($arr_ajax);
```

And with this code, when I click on Submit button, I get the following response in my browser console:

```
index.html:79 success
index.html:80 {namePro: "Test Product", price: "100.00", stock: "15", Filename0: "faces1.jpg"}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't work, I don't know why, if you want I can share the project with data base to solve this, because I want to continue. I'm having problems because I downloaded that code from github and I'm adding tha part of the information. Let me know if you could check it and I share the complete project, I don't have problem with that.

Comment: Can you please first just share the complete JS file you have? And also does your code works with only files? Does i upload them and insert them in the db? Do you get any errors?

Comment: I'm only having problems with the part of the information, the code works uploading only the images to the database. Let me add the code

Comment: I want to know how you add your other form elements to your formData object? if you are using `var namePro = document.getElementsByName('name');` it's incorrect. If you are using either of the ways I suggested, it should work. If it's not working, what you get in the response in your developer tools of your browser?

Comment: Nothing, the code stays loading but nothing happen, when I add only the images the code works and upload the images into the data base but with the information it stays loading and  I added that you told me, thats why I want to share the project, I'm learning with this but there are a lot of things that I don't understand yet.
I Appreciate your help

Comment: So the code is working fine on my machine with only 1 small change. You are adding an element to your formData object with the name of namePro `formData.append('namePro', namePro);` But then in your php you are looking for name `$namePRO = $_REQUEST['name'];` which is not in your payload and that causes a php parser error. Either change `namePro` in your js to `name` or change `name` in your php to `namePro` and you should be good to go

Comment: I edited that part, really sorry I don't know why the code is not working on my machine

Comment: I think it's better to edit your question, remove all the code that you have in there, then add your latest html/js/php code back in so I can know what you have there as your latest code which is still not working as it is working fine on my machine(I've removed all the upload and database insertion parts as I assume those parts are working fine)

Comment: Ok I edit the question and posted the code that I have now, I appreciate your help

Comment: I was thinking, and I have somethings that maybe I don't need in the code, And maybe thays why the code in my machine doesn't work. I'm gonna try in other project to see if the code works or not, Could you please post the code that you have to see if it works for me?, I think I have to change some parts of the code yet. I would really appreciate

Comment: @Sebastian I've updated my answer with the sample code that works on my machine. Please give it a try and see if it works for you or not. If not, can you please let me know if you get any errors in your browser console?

Comment: It´s working, I change one part to insert them into the DB and it works. A lot of thanks. :D